How to find the width of the columns of a mat-table
I have a mat-table and would like to be able to find the widths (in pixels) of its columns. I have a stackblitz here which, when the button is clicked, gets the table html element and puts up an alert to show that it has a valid element.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-um5cut?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html.
How can I modify the code to display (for example) the width of, say, column 2?
Thanks.

You can use the below code, which I already made for another answer, This will work for the latest versions of angular.
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  @ViewChildren(MatHeaderCell, { read: ElementRef })
  headers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  OnClick() {
    const headersArray = this.headers.toArray();
    console.log(
      'width of column 1 ',
      headersArray[1]?.nativeElement?.getBoundingClientRect()?.width || 0
    );
  }
}


Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work for me on my stackblitz, which I've modified (headersArray.length = 0), but maybe because that's on too old a version of Angular? I tried the stackblitz from your other answer but when I browse to it the app doesn't run, just a black screen.

@gnitsuk try this stackblitz if it does not run, you can download the code and run in local system
